# How to Properly Add a Branch to An Already Existing Tree

Tags: c++, floating-point, stdvector, root-framework

I am calculating the invariant mass from a dimuon channel.

I am using the RDataFrame to do this calculations. 
A snippet of my code is as follows:

```
// Enable multi-threading
   ROOT::EnableImplicitMT();
   // Create dataframe from NanoAOD files
   ROOT::RDataFrame df("Delphes;6",
                      "tag_1_delphes_events.root");
   //auto mu_mass = df.Define("muon_mass", "0.1");
   // For simplicity, select only events with exactly two muons and require opposite charge
   //auto df_2mu = df.Filter("nMuon == 2", "Events with exactly two muons");
   auto df_os = df.Filter("Muon.Charge[0] != Muon.Charge[1]", "Muons with opposite charge");
   // Compute invariant mass of the dimuon system
   auto df_mu_mass = df_os.Define("muon_mass", "0.1");
   auto df_mass = df_mu_mass.Define("Dimuon_mass", InvariantMass<float>, {"Muon.PT", "Muon.Eta", "Muon.Phi", "muon_mass"});
   // Make histogram of dimuon mass spectrum
   auto h = df_mass.Histo1D({"Dimuon_mass", "Dimuon_mass", 30000, 0.25, 300}, "Dimuon_mass");
   // Request cut-flow report
   auto report = df_mass.Report();
   // Produce plot
```

My PT, eta, Phi, values are float values. The error I get is that :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  RColumnValue: type specified for column "muon_mass" is ROOT::VecOps::RVec<float> but temporary column has type double
```

I tried to insert the RVec in front of 0.1 in my Define, but that didn't work. 
How can I fix this problem to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I found to fix this problem is by adding the branch value manually in my Tree